# inject Overylay icons in finder mac os x

Tags: macos, finder

I am trying to inject my code for overlayicons in finder in all the three views, 
but not able to do it for mac os 10.9 and above, kindly help me in this 
for 10.8 and below versions i am able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the new Finder Sync? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html